# Problem in getting Value through POST method after Login

Tags: forms

I am creating an **eCommerce theme**. I have created 3 Pages – **Contribute Page**, **Login Page** & **Checkout Page**.

On **Contribute Page** there is a form. Following is the code:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.example.com/login">

  <input type="number" name="amount" min="1" placeholder="Total Amount" required>
  <button type="submit" >Continue</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_title" value="I just want to pay this amount." />

</form>
```

On Login Page there is a **Login Form**. Following is the code:

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="POST"> 
          <ul>                                                    
             <li>Email</li>
             <li> <input type="text" id="user_login" name="log" placeholder="Email ID" value="" size="20"></li>
             <li>Password</li>
             <li><input type="password" class="form-control" id="user_pass" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" value="" size="20"></li>
             <li><input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" name="rememberme" value="forever"> Remember me</li>
             <li><button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="wp-submit" name="wp-submit" value="Log In">Login</button></li>
          </ul>
             <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://www.example.com/checkout?amount=<?php echo $_REQUEST['amount']; ?>&amount_title=<?php echo $_REQUEST['amount_title']; ?>" />
</form>
```

And on **Checkout Page** following is the code:

```
<?php echo $_REQUEST['amount']; ?>
<?php echo $_REQUEST['amount_title']; ?>
```

Every thing is working perfect. The value of the ‘**amount**‘ is echoing perfectly on **Checkout Page** but the value of ‘**amount_title**‘ is not echoing proper.

I want the value to be echoed as “**I just want to pay this amount.**” But it is echoing as “**Ijustwanttopaythisamount.**”

I want the sentence with the space in between words. Plz help me to get solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Spaces in GET parameters need to be encoded.

```
amount_title=<?php echo urlencode( $_REQUEST['amount_title'] ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Milo. It works perfect. Can you tell me how to hide URL Parameters or encrypt GET Values.